# What is the difference between `open (-a) <app>` and double click in finder/spotlight?

Tags: terminal, finder, homebrew, spotlight

I recently installed [leksah](//leksah.org) on my Mac (once directly, once via brew cask).

When I try to open it in Finder, Dock or use spotlight the window flashes open for a second and then closes immediately. 
When I open it via terminal using `open -a Leksah` or `open ~/Applications/Leksah` it opens just fine.

Other users have experienced the same issue with other apps and other OSX versions as well. Is there a difference in behavior when opening an application using any of these methods? How can one debug what's going on?

Comment: I have recently seen the same issue with a different application (`DBeaver`) on High Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one difference is that via Command Line, you can pass the file to be opened as an argument, but I guess this is not the difference you are after.

The behaviour you speak of appears to be a bug which can be observed when running Yosemite. The issue is still open: https://github.com/leksah/leksah/issues/37